# WordPress theme responsive issue with RTL direction

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using WordPress and I've got a free WordPress theme called Sydney,
When I'm editing it as a RTL direction language and check it on my smartphone to see its responsiveness, I see a little gap from the left hand side of the page.

I want to mention that when I check it with the emulator plugin of WordPress or other tools, it doesn't show any gap at all, so it seems as full responsive which is not actually,
And When I change it to LTR direction, it's really full responsive on my device and no gaps at all, but the content changes the alignment to the left instead of to the right.

This is a screenshot from my device:

[image: Screenshot of the device]

Hope you can help me fix this issue, 
Thank you.

Comment: a screenshot alone won't allow to find the problem - you need to post your code

Comment: I barely use code for creating this website, it's all wordpress what code should I need to upload? css?

Comment: @user3561607 Could you post a URL to your site?